# Viewing flag history if no flags are marked "helpful"

Tags: support, flags, flag-history

I have flagged 2 answers and I want to view the status of those flags. Where can I view them?

Once a flag is marked as "helpful", I can see a link to "helpful flags" on my profile near the profile picture. But if I don't have any helpful flags, how can I see them?

Comment: Its just irritating, why did this question get downvoted? If i am new here, then should not i even be enquiring about something??

Comment: Downvotes mean "this question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful". They don't mean "we hate you because you are new", and they don't necessarily mean "you should not be inquiring about this". Someone probably thought either that you should have been able to find out the answer yourself with a bit of research, or that the answers to this question are unlikely to be useful to anyone else but you.

Comment: I am asking something I dont know. Its not about programming logic, or algorithm or any reasearch article that i would be searching knowing some keywords. If people like me can have problem finding something, why dont SO provide a guide on the user-interface?? They provide terms and conditions, rules and regulations, etc but can't they provide guidelines on interface view?

Comment: WHy this question has been tagged duplicate? I think people misunderstand it. I clearly mentioned "Once a flag is marked as "helpful", I can see a link to "helpful flags" on my profile near the profile picture. But if I don't have any helpful flags, how can I see them?"

Comment: The question to which my question has been stated duplicate, see the accepted answer over there.. Thats why I already mentioned. If i have at least one helpfull flag, then i can visit the link in the helpfull flag, if i dont have, then how can i go??

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> But if I don't have any helpful flags, how can I see them?

By directly visiting the URL: http://www.stackoverflow.com/users/flag-summary/3937178

Comment: @SmrutiSingh, this link is also in your profile.  Click on the number listed next to "helpful flags"

Comment: that link only coms if i have atleast one helpful flag. See my question what i realy asked. Say my first flag isnt approved yet, or it has been declined, then i cant see the hrlpful flag link. Then how can i visit the flag links

Comment: page not found.

Comment: @Imad that link is only visible to OP. User's flag summary page is not public, its visible to the user only. For you the link would be http://www.stackoverflow.com/users/flag-summary/3664659